# How can I fetch all job openings data by using zoho recruiter API?

Tags: zoho

I want to fetch all the jobs that I posted on my Zoho recruit. And I want to fetch all those jobs on my website for that I use the below API.

```
curl "https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/v2/jobopening"
-X GET
-H "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.8cb99dxxxxxxxxxxxxx9be93.9b8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf"
```

Scope:
`scope=ZohoRECRUIT.modules.jobopening.READ`

I use all the necessary parameters but still it give the error like

```json
{
    "code": "INTERNAL_ERROR",
    "details": {},
    "message": "EXTRA_PARAM_FOUND",
    "status": "error"
}
```

Comment: "EXTRA_PARAM_FOUND" is a big hint as to what's going wrong here. Check the API docs.